# How do I inherit a variable from a parent class?

Tags: java, variables, inheritance, parent-child, subclass

I have a subclass that needs to inherit a method and a variable, and I want to be able to make several instances of the subclass. However, I can't change `health`'s value from the class Glob.

Here is my code:

```
public class Monster
{
int health;

    public int getHealth()
    {
        return health;
    }
}

class Glob extends Monster
{
    health = 6; //  <- Error
}
```

Comment: You have not specific what is the problem.  The code you posted seems valid, but where is the code where you're *trying to make it work*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just shadow variable of superclass like that. You can do it in constructor though -

```
class Glob extends Monster
{
    public Glob() {
        health = 6;
    }
}
```